# Incorrect time-conversion in Go

Tags: go, time

I am trying to convert the time string "2020-02-01T12:30:00+01:00" (from the google calendar API) to time.Time format in Go, for some reason it keeps giving me "2020-01-01 12:30:00 +0000 UTC" as output (which is first of January, instead of first of February). Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "log"
)

func main() {

    input := "2020-02-01T12:30:00+01:00"
    output, err := StrToTime(input)
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(output)


}

func StrToTime(strDateTime string) (time.Time, error) {

    layout := "2006-01-02T15:04:05+01:00"
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, strDateTime)

    if err != nil {
        return time.Time{}, fmt.Errorf("could not parse datetime: %v", err)
    }

    return t, nil

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It happens because you've specified the time offset portion wrong, it should be `-07:00` not `+01:00`.

As of now it treats `01` as month portion, the second time, and overwrites the originally correctly parsed `02` as `01` (but not from the time offset part of the input).